# Laptop crashes at 60 c

Tags: temperature

I own a Sony Vaio VPCEA1S1E that is around 4 years old, though the fan was replaced just a few months ago. It was working just fine until yesterday (no crashes) it started turning itself off whenever I turned it on for a few seconds. I waited overnight because I suspected it might be an overheating problem, so I just turned it on now and downloaded Speedfan to check the temperature. And as it turns out, it crashes whenever the temperature gets to 60 degrees celsius. What should I do? I don't think laptops are supposed to turn off at just 60 degrees...

Comment: If indeed it is overheating related, it's possible the part overheating is some distance from, and quite hotter than, the temperature sensor you are looking at.  Or the sensor you are watching could be bad, or a different faulty one could be triggering a protective shutdown that looks like a crash.  Or perhaps there are incompatible reporting mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

With a computer 4 years old, you've got age related degredation occurring in the silicon. It seems a bit premature, but it's likely that you've got a marginal part to begin with, and over time with heat, degredation happens faster. As Chris stated, you've got some part of it that's much hotter than 60 degrees at the temp sensor. At that high of a temperature, some transistor is likely malfunctioning and some 0 gets turned into a 1 or vice versa. Then a transaction gets lost or you've jumped to a place that doesn't exist or some other equally dead condition. Your options at this point are to:

1. Ensure you run it cool by not making it run too hard and run the fan at max at all times.
2. Buy a new laptop.
3. Try removing or swapping the memory around and see if it's your memory that's failing.

Answer (score 0):

CMOS runs slower when hot and thus if there is insufficient timing margin in the RAM being used and its bios preset values, it can fail when hot.  Consider disabling all useless apps and AV programs, Windows search service etc to get well under 40 Processes under the process tab  in Task Mgr on boot.  ( Ideal is 16 on boot for XP, most have >50 )    Then CpU will run 10 deg cooler and you can salvage laptop and make it run faster. AV programs are so bloated that they are as bad as viruses (IMHO)

.  i use winpatrol, autoruns.exe ,or  if desparate, msconfig to disable startup apps and services not required. This takes eperience and if you need support send a log file from any startup mgr program like Winpatrol (free). There are many other tools to trim wasted CPU.